# Linking Data Fields from Different Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, columnsorting

I have reports that I run frequently from 2 different sources that both have one unique identifier that links the data across both reports (I'll call the field ID "LINK ID").  This field appears in both sets of exports (however the exports are from 2 different systems that populate different data points). I typically cut and paste each report to separate sheets within a newly created workbook and then go about matching them up.

At one point I had worked on a subroutine that would cycle through the column that contained the "LINK ID" in one sheet, and then cycle through the other column that contained the same "LINK ID" on the other worksheet, and if it found a match it would copy the entire row of data linked to that match and paste it over onto the first worksheet.

The code that I had worked on never got completely finished, but I am trying to see if I can figure out this once and for all because it would be AWESOME if I didn't have to sift through these with my eyes one at a time.

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub Find_And_Link()

Dim rw As Long

Dim mr2 As Long

Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws3 = Sheets("VM")   

With Sheets("AY")

For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

If CBool(Application.CountIf(ws3.Columns(1), .Cells(rw, "F").Value)) Then

mrw = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, "F"), ws3.Columns(1), 0)

ws3.Cells(mrw, "A").Resize(1, 12).Copy _
Destination:=.Cells(rw, "G")
ws3.Rows(mrw).EntireRow.Delete
'getting rid of the row if match found

End If

Next rw

End With

Set ws3 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: A quick note: when using `With`, make sure that any range type references are explicit.  I notice you may want to update your `For rw = 2 ...` line, as it currently isn't explicit which sheet's Rows.Count to use...so change that to `For rw = 2 to .Cells(.Rows.Count,"F").End(xlUp).Row` to ensure it's counting "AY" sheet's rows.  With your current code, what's wrong with it? Does it not loop completely, or do you get an error?

Comment: Thank you.  So... just to be clear, should I include the .Sheets reference somewhere within the `For rw = 2...` line?  Currently, when I run the code it does absolutely nothing.  It doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't appear to be changing anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I was able to get.  I made an assumption that your sheet "AY" is the original sheet that you want the data copied *to*, and "VM" is the sheet you're searching for the data to copy *from* (change this if it's backwards).  I also changed the variable names to be a little more clear:

```
Sub Find_And_Link()

Dim i As Long, copyRow As Long

Dim origWS As Worksheet, copyWS As Worksheet

Set copyWS = Sheets("VM")
Set origWS = Sheets("AY")

With origWS
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        If CBool(Application.CountIf(copyWS.Columns(1), .Cells(i, "F").Value)) Then
            copyRow = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "F"), copyWS.Columns(1), 0)
            Debug.Print "Match found in row " & copyRow & "."
            copyWS.Cells(copyRow, "A").Resize(1, 12).Copy Destination:=.Cells(i, "G")
            copyWS.Rows(copyRow).EntireRow.Delete 'getting rid of the row if match found
        Else
            Debug.Print "No match found for Link ID " & .Cells(i, 6) & " :("
        End If
    Next i
End With

Set copyWS = Nothing

End Sub
```

I tried this and it worked.  Note: In "AY", your "Link IDs" are all in column F.  In "VM", the "Link IDs" are all in Column A.

This will find a match in "VM", copy the data from column A to L, then paste that in "AY", column G through S.  Note that it's not quite what you asked (you asked to replace the entire row in the original sheet), but I did this because it's in your code.

To instead replace the entire line in your original "AY" sheet, change the Copy destination to `Destination:=.Cells(i,"A")`.  (You might want to add `.Rows(i).Clear` before that line to clear any data in that row.)

Comment: Wow, this is great.  Thank you for all of your help.  I am still experiencing the same problem (I run the code in a Module and it says it has run but nothing has changed).  I checked and there are definitely items that _should_ be matching, however I am not sure why it would not be running anything.  I have checked my reference library but it appears to be current.

Comment: Can you post a sample screenshot of both sheets? I'll update my OP with some debugging lines, to at least check that things are working.  (You'll see the "debug.print" stuff in the VB window, in the Immediate Window (press CTRL+G to see it)).  Also, make sure that the sheet names are correct - perhaps I have them reversed?  Another tip is to step through your Macro with `F8` on the keyboard, it'll go line by line.  Then, you can see if it skips the `If` statement completely, which would result in nothing happening.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers!  In the end, it was totally my fault.  One system exports data with leading empty spaces and the other does not.  I used the Trim function and ran your code and it worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for your work and help!